# How to find the referencing ObjectId and remove it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a Location schema and a Catch schema. When a user adds his catch to a specific location, it creates an ObjectId reference in the location schema. Here's the problem, when a user removes the catch, the catch is deleted from the Catch schema, but the referencing ObjectId in the Location schema remains, creating a broken reference. I have been working on this problem for a few weeks, no idea if I'm missing something. I've read the docs and stack-overflowed this issue for hours and hours on end for the past few days. I have tried adding a pre-hook middleware, but after spending a few days debugging it I just couldn't get it to work. Is this possible to do with mongoose?

Here is my location schema:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    gps: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    catches: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Catch"
        }
        ]
});
```

And my Catch schema:

```
var catchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    species: String,
    weight: String,
    image: String,
    catchlocation: String,
    catchlocationid: String,
    description: String,
    timePosted: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
},
   {timestamps: true}
);
```

EDIT: Added the delete catch route:

```
app.delete("/locations/:id/catch/:catchid", isUserPost, function(req, res){
    Catch.findById(req.params.catchid, function(err, post){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
        post.remove(function(err){
                    req.flash("success", "Your catch has been deleted.");
                    res.redirect("/locations/" + req.params.id);
        })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code for deleting of catch you have used

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: Inside Catch find query after removal of catch statement(after post.remove), write find query with that ref in location collection and apply delete for location

Comment: Okay. Would I use findByIdAndRemove? I looked all over the mongoose docs but couldn&#39;t find something that would work in this situation. I am using mongoose 4.

Comment: yes remove documents

Comment: Is it different for removing a ObjectId in a subdocument?

Comment: Would it be like ref.catches.id(_id).remove or do I need to do another find to find that specific ObjectId reference?

Comment: Do another find and the remove specific

Comment: Okay. I'll post the code here when I get it in case anyone else is running into the same problem. Thank you for the help!